# if I don't use static keyword with a method still I can call this method like a static method in php 7.4. does anyone know why?

Tags: php, oop, methods, static, static-methods

As I knew we create static methods to call them outside the class without instantiating it. Therefore we use the keyword static with our methods and we can call them with the help of the scope resolution operator '::'. But the confusion is if I don't use the keyword static with the definition of the method I can still call it a static method without instantiating the class. Could please anyone tell me what is happening here?

Comment: Please share your code which you are executing, because what you said is not going to work: https://3v4l.org/bF6VP  And https://3v4l.org/pHbpk

Comment: @Anant-Alivetodie it gives a deprecation warning for the 7.4.x versions only, so maybe OP is simply suppressing these, and therefor doesn't see anything going wrong? As long as the method in question is not using the `$this` keyword, it might actually all work as it is supposed to ... But relying on that is of course not recommendable, I think we agree on that.

Comment: @CBroe yes agreed, even if it happens in the 7.4x version but it gives a clear warning, as well as the basic idea, is not to rely on it as the concept of Oops gets violated.

Comment: <?php

class MehodTest {

    public function check(){
        echo 'Check is Called';
    }

}

//confusion
MehodTest::check();

?>
@Anant-Alivetodie I am executing this code.

Comment: @khalilahmad https://3v4l.org/Sbbpf .. if you run it you will get a fatal error in the 8 versions, the code is executed with a deprecation warning for the 7 versions. In the older version, you will get a strict standard warning or parse error straight forward. so the basic idea is to resolve all types of errors in your code even if it is a warning on an undefined index errors. So when you do that eventually you have to follow the rule.Surpassing errors like warning and other is not a goog idea